# Custom Element is not working in IE 11 after transpiling

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, web-component, custom-element, polyfills

I have created a reusable web component and for this question's sake, let's call it `<custom-el>`. To invoke this custom element's implementation, I am writing it in my template files as following `<custom-el class="container-for-custom-tag"></custom-el>` and in the component, I am adding the children to this tag. When the browser engine finds out this tag, my component gets invoked and it adds children to this tag.

To make it work in IE 11, I have used document-register-element polyfill and it transpiles the file successfully. I don't get any errors in IE 11 when I load this transpiled file. But since the tag  is also not recognized in IE11, nothing renders in UI. What am I doing wrong here?

I tried using babel plugins as well, I get the same result. The file gets transpiled but nothing renders in UI because of the tag.

Now, I have a solution in mind to invoke the web component on demand instead of it getting invoked because of the HTML tag. But I really want to know is there anything else which can be done to solve it. I saw on GitHub page of document-register-element that they have also put the custom tag in the HTML page in the examples but how is it working for them that I am not sure of.

This is how I am defining my custom Element:

```
class CustomEl extends HTMLElement {
 // Inside this I render the child elements
 // This HTML gets appended to the custom-el as children: 
 //<div class="text-container">20</div>
 // I m not using shadow root
}
// Here I define the custom element
customElements.define('custom-el', CustomEl);
```

This is how I have invoked it:

```
// The following code goes in the template HTML file
<div class=“wrapper-container”>
 <custom-el id="js-custom-el-conatiner”></custom-el>
<div>
```

When I load it in the browser, I get the following output in the browser inspector:

```
<div class=“wrapper-container”>
    <custom-el id="js-custom-el-conatiner” >
         <div class="text-container">20</div>
    </custom-el>
<div>
```

For IE, I have required `polyfill/document-register-element`in this file as per the github page [documentation](https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element). `class CustomEl extends HTMLElement` gets compiled and I don't get any syntax error or any kind of error in the file. But since the HTML tag is still `<custom-el>` which invokes the implementation, it doesn't get invoked because that element is not recognized by IE browser engine.

Comment: Does no one know the answer to it? Does No one have any hint to solve it?

Comment: A code example would help here, if possible? Where are you calling `customElements.define`? How are you adding content into the custom element? Are you using Shadow DOM?

Comment: +1 for code example; try to reproduce your problem in a JSFiddle, CodePen, anything. IE is a pain, you waist about 15 to 20% of your development time on IE issues.

Comment: @lamplightdev I have added the code example.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman After this update also, if it's not helpful I will create a fiddle as well. Let me know.

Comment: Hi Neha - I think a fiddle would help then we can pinpoint the problem exactly. One thing from the code you posted - there seems to be some 'smart' quotes (the curly ones, rather than the standard straight ones) in there, e.g. around the `wrapper-container` class. That maybe just a copy and paste issue, but I imagine that would cause some issues too if not.

Answer (score 4):

It's not JS issue here - you have proved the custom element does its job and makes it into DOM. Now, make sure you have applied CSS to that element, basically telling browser how to render it. Start with basic `display` property. Without JSFiddle or CodePen or anything to play with it's hard to tell you the exact issue. Most of the times it's the problem to get a custom element into IE11 due to the fact it does not support ES6 constructs that are needed and one has to rely on polyfills like https://github.com/webcomponents/polyfills/tree/master/packages/webcomponentsjs